# How do 2 pairs of wings work?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I have a character that has a pair of draconic wings from the feat of the same name.
I would like to use the cloak of the dragon from complete champion page 138. It says that I "grow a pair of draconic wings"

If I use something that gives me wings while having natural wings for the added flight time, how would my natural wings interact with the extra ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, wings overlap, not stack with each other. If you sprout new wings, your old wings just transform. There are no special rules, at least to what I've found, for multiple sets of wings. Even creatures with multiple sets like giant dragonflies and stirges don't have any special rules.

However, do note that the Draconic Wings feat doesn't give you wings, only allows you to glide with the wings you already have (which seems kinda...useless, but hey).

Comment: Improved draconic wings lets you fly

Comment: I can't find reference for an improved draconic wings feat (likely due to my books not being here atm, and Wizards giving the order to shut down the massive index of feats and classes that was online). But that wasn't what was in the question, so I didn't look for it. You might be right.

Answer (score 3):

Unless one or both sets of wings are stated to grant you a Wing Buffet attack (which may have been more of a Pathfinder thing) you may be able to convince your DM that you could use one set as natural weapons while in midair while using the other set to fly like normal, but other than that, there's no real mechanical benefit to having multiple sets of wings.

As you may have already heard, wing effects overlap, not stack, so you would just use whichever set grants you the better fly speed/maneuverability and the other set becomes redundant.

Of course, if your DM says otherwise than you would be able to benefit from two wing sets however he says, but as far as the rules go you really don't want to waste feat/magic item slots on something like redundant sets of wings.

Comment: It's just so I can fly for 10 more minutes a day. It also adds flavor to my character and gives me a breath weapon.

Comment: If you already have a natural fly speed then you probably won't need the limited duration flight granted by the cloak. Breath weapon bit I understand, though I suspect there might be a more efficient way to get one of those, too.

Actually, have you looked into the Dragonfire Adept from Dragon Magic? Because they got a breath weapon as a class feature and eventually get winged flight as an at-will invocation.

Comment: Dragonfighter adept is primarily a spellcaster. I'm going for an archer build. And my natural flight speed is also limited to 10 minutes. That's why I might need the extra pair of wings.

Comment: What then is the source of this natural flight speed?

Comment: Improved draconic wings

Comment: It just says you're fatigued after 10 total minutes and after attempting to fly again after that, not necessarily that you can't fly at all for the rest of the day. In fact, it actually recommends outright using Glide to extend your air time since it doesn't count as actual flight. Plus, the whole "exhaustion from flying" thing goes away entirely at character level 12.